# Please show error in my proof!

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

**Theorem**:(*from Lecture Notes*) Given a function $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ and sets $A_i \subset X$ and $B_i \subset Y$, $i\in \mathbb{N}$, we have: $$f(\cap_{i=1}^\infty A_i) \subseteq \cap_{i=1}^\infty f(A_i).$$

My proof was based on the idea to show that all elements that belong to LHS also belong to RHS:

Proof:
Let $a_1\in \cap_{i=1}^\infty A_i.$ This implies that $f(a_1) \in f(\cap_{i=1}^\infty A_i)$. Since $a_1\in \cap_{i=1}^\infty A_i, a_1 \in A_i,\forall i \in \mathbb{N}.$ Now,  $f(a_1) \in f(A_i),\forall i \in \mathbb{N}$ which implies that $f(a_1) \in \cap_{i=1}^\infty f(A_i).$  $\blacksquare$

I don't think this is correct! But I cannot figure out where I am missing.

**EDIT:** The reason I feel this is wrong is the following:

It also easily follows (just change the order of statements from the proof above) from same argument that $f(\cap_{i=1}^\infty A_i) \supseteq \cap_{i=1}^\infty f(A_i).$ This will of course imply that $f(\cap_{i=1}^\infty A_i)= \cap_{i=1}^\infty f(A_i)$, which **should** be wrong since the Lecture notes say that the last implication is only true if $f$ is injective. But I have never used injectivity in my proof. Or did I implicitly? Is injectivity really necessary?

I'm sorry to ask again. All your comments seems helpful to me but I am still unsatisfied.

Comment: How do you know such an a can be chosen?  Perhaps the intersection is the empty set which would be a special case to handle in your proof.

Comment: Looks correct to me. What was bothering you? Another way of writing the above is to notice that since $\cap_i A_i \subset A_j$ for all $j$, then $f(\cap_i A_i) \subset f(A_j)$ for all $j$, from which you have $f(\cap_i A_i) \subset \cap_j f(A_j)$.

Comment: Looks ok, except that I would start with "Take $b \in f(\cap_{i=1}^\infty A_i)$. Then $b = f(a_1)$ for some $a_1 \in \cap_{i=1}^\infty A_i$." and proceed as you did at "Since...". This way it is more clear that you take an arbitrary element in the LSH and show that it is also a member of the RHS.

Comment: @JBKing This proof still works in the case of empty intersection: to prove the result, you need to prove that every $b\in f(\cap A_i)$ is also contained in $\cap f(a_i)$. If there is no such $b$, then this is pretty easy to show!

Comment: While that is true, there could be someone that wants to point out, "Hey, what if there isn't such an a?" as it is more for the sake of completeness that this is worth adding in the notes of the proof.

Comment: Let $z\in f[\,\bigcap_i A_i\,]$. Then there is a $x\in \bigcap_i A_i$ such that $f(x)=z$. Let $i$ be arbitrary. Clearly $x\in A_i$, and then $f(x)\in f[\, A_i\,]$ for an arbitrary $i$. Since $i$ was arbitrary $z=f(x)\in \bigcap_i f[\, A_i\,]$ as desired.

Comment: @JoseAntonio thanks!

Comment: @ILOVEMATH: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a minor thing: you should start with $y ∈ f(⋂_i A_i)$ and show that $y ∈ ⋂_i f(A_i)$. For this $y$ you can choose your $a_1$. This also handles the case that $⋂_i A_i$ is empty. Also note that you don't need that index set is $\mathbb{N}$. It holds with same proof for any index set.

For edited question: The minor thing also forbids you to prove the other inclusion in the same manner. If $y ∈ ⋂_i f(A_i)$ then for any $i$ there is $a_i ∈ A_i$ such that $f(a_i) = y$. But you have no guarantee that all these $a_i$s are equal. Note that it would work if $f$ was injective (and for the same reason it works also for preimages).